# How to exit the application in App Inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have programmed an Android application with App Inventor that contains 3 screens. The first for login, second for menu and the third for profile.

The problem is when I have in login and I clicked on return hurry it opens the menu but in the code, I give when click on back pressed left the application

Here are my blocks
[image]

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: [The recommended method of switching screens in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use the function "close application" in control section of blocks

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to close the application if you are testing with the companion or emulator. Close application works only when using the built apk.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not properly managing the screens, this is why it goes to your MENU screen. Check out this App Inventor tutorial that covers handling multiple screens:

https://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/colored-dots.html